# What kind of matrix norm satisifies $\text {norm} (A*B)\leq \text {norm} (A)*\text {norm} (B)$ in which A is square?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

$||A\times B||\le ||A||\cdot ||B||$  is not always correct. But which kind of matrix norm satisifies this formula for square matrix $A$ and arbitrary matrix $B$?

Comment: Your use of the singular form "norm" (rather than "norms") is confusing. Since $B$ is not necessarily square, $AB,\,A$ and $B$ in general live in different matrix spaces. Therefore, in the inequality $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$, *three* norms are actually involved.

Comment: Yes, but I just want a norm defined for matrix of arbitrary shape to meet the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Operator norms (induced by any norms on vectors of the appropriate dimensions) satisfy $\|A B\| \le \|A \| \|B \|$.

Comment: I do not think so, if A and B is [3,1] and [4;1], respectively. and define the norm as the max absolute value of matrix elements. ||A*B|| = 14 > ||A||*||B|| = 12

Comment: That is not an operator norm.  Given norms $\| \cdot\|_m$ and $\|\cdot \|_n$ on $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$, the corresponding operator norm on $m \times n$ real matrices is $\|A\| = \max(\|A x\|_m : \|x\|_n = 1)$.

Comment: I read the wiki page. I see the matrix is treated as a linear operator mapping vector in $R^m$ to $R^n$. You mean for operator norm, given a unit vector, mapping of $A\times B$ produce a vector with lesser length than the product of separate action of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $\|ABx\| \le \|A\| \|Bx\| \le \|A\| \|B\| \|x\|$

Comment: Thanks for your reply professor, I think I resolved this question. I just posted another question related to this question, would you please have a look at it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266683/how-close-is-cartesian-product-of-unit-orthogonal-bases-of-svd-to-identity-matri)